# Multiple Jquery UI Dialogs on One Page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

I have multiple Jquery UI Dialogs on one page and am having difficulties getting the modals to load the correct content. I'm generating ID's dynamically for the divs around the images I"m trying to load for each one. The code I have below is generating the ID's but each "thumbnail", when clicked is loading the wrong corresponding image in the dialog box. Any ideas? Thanks in advance for your help!

Here's my code....

HTML: (an example of what the thumbnail and dialog code looks like) 
(the id="ui-id-36" and id="ui-id-35" is what's getting generated dynamically).

```
<div class="dialog-wrapper">
    <div class="dialog-thumbnail"><a href="link-to-image-1.png"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="link-to-thumbnail-1.png"></a>
        <div class="dialog-image" id="ui-id-35"><img src="link-to-larger-image-1.png"></div>
   </div>
</div> 

<div class="dialog-wrapper">
    <div class="dialog-thumbnail"><a href="link-to-image-2.png"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="link-to-thumbnail-2.png"></a>
        <div class="dialog-image" id="ui-id-36"><img src="link-to-larger-image-2.png">
        </div>
   </div>
```

```
jQuery: 
   var id = $('.dialog-thumbnail > .dialog-image').uniqueId().attr('id');
   $('#' + id).dialog({
      autoOpen: false, 
      modal: true,
    });
    $('.dialog-thumbnail').data('linked-dialog-id', id).on('click', function (e) {
      var id = $(this).data('linked-dialog-id');
      $('#' + id).dialog("open");
      event.preventDefault();
    });
```